# Set boost on fields using Lucene

Tags: lucene

I am implementing word search using Lucene.
I want to ad two fields for each document: a title field, which contains the first 100 characters from the document and a contents field, which contains the rest of the characters from the document.

```
ContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();

    try {
        parser.parse(is, handler, metadata);
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }

    Document doc = new Document();
    Field titleField = new Field("title", 
                           handler.toString().substring(0, 100), 
                           Field.Store.YES, 
                           Field.Index.ANALYZED_NO_NORMS);

    Field contentsField = new Field("contents", 
                              handler.toString().substring(101), 
                              Field.Store.YES, 
                              Field.Index.ANALYZED_NO_NORMS);
```

I want to add boosting to each field: I want the title to count 70% and the content to count 30%.

I am doing it like this:

```
titleField.setBoost(1.70f);

doc.add(titleField);
doc.add(contentsField);
doc.add(new Field("filename", metadata.get(Metadata.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY), 
        Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
```

However, I cannot see the diferrence for the documents procentually.

Does the length of the field matter in calculationg the scorting?

I have also try to implement a class which extends DefaultSimilarity, but it does not help.

```
class IsolationSimilarity extends DefaultSimilarity {
    public IsolationSimilarity(){
    }

    @Override
    public float idf(int docFreq, int numDocs) {
        return(float)1.0;
    }

    @Override
    public float coord(int overlap, int maxOverlap) {
        return 1.0f;
    }

    @Override
    public float lengthNorm(String fieldName, int numTokens){
        return 1.0f;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried increasing the amount that you boost the field?  Keep in mind that [the method used of encoding that value](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-BETA/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html#encodeNormValue%28float%29) is *Extremely* lossy, in order to save space in the index.  You can only count on about 1 significant digit of precision.

Try a much larger value, and then pull it back until you have it tuned that way you want.

That said, you should see some small difference between the two.  Based on my testing, 1.7 will get to the Similarity with an end value of 1.5, when lengthNorm has been stubbed.

Have you run [`explain()`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#explain%28org.apache.lucene.search.Query,%20int%29), to see what is influencing your query?  Just because you've boost the title, doesn't mean a match on title will be the first result returned.